# Sed command: how to search for the second line occurrence starting from a word?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I have this file `simple.yml`:

```
services:
  - name: first
    image: first_image
    versionId: 1.0.0_first_image_id
  - name: second
    image: second_image
    versionId: 2.0.1_second_image_id
```

I'm trying to replace the second occurrence of `versionId` with this value: `versionId: image_id_edited` so that the file would look like this:

```
services:
  - name: first
    image: first_image
    versionId: 1.0.0_first_image_id
  - name: second
    image: second_image
    versionId: image_id_edited
```

The value `2.0.1_second_image_id` here is changed often, so I cannot do a static search. Currently, I have this `sed` command but it's not working:

```
sed -rz "s/versionId:\s*.*\$/versionId: image_id_edited/2" -i simple.yaml
```

I'd like to have a regex to search for the second `versionId: ...` until it reaches the end of the line! Thanks!

Comment: There's definitely a problem with your `sed` command, but I'm confused about why you think it has to do with not searching to the end of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be counting on the `-z` flag to cause the whole input to be interpreted as a single line, so that the `2` flag to your `s` command results in the second match in the whole file being substituted.  The problem is that the relevant count is over *non-overlapping* matches.  Your pattern being anchored to the end of the line, you need to match in multiline mode in order for there to be a possibility of two non-overlapping matches:

```
sed -rz 's/versionId:\s*.*$/versionId: image_id_edited/m2' -i simple.yaml
```

That is, add an `m` flag to the `s` command.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. And thank you so much for the detailed explanation!